# Does Android 2.3 support ad-hoc Wi-Fi networks?

Tags: 2.3-gingerbread, ad-hoc-networks

Does Android 2.3 have support for adhoc networking without rooting or at least support it better with rooting? The list of stuff added for 2.3 just said bug fixes, I was wondering if anyone knew what bugs they were fixing or had a link to a list.

Comment: Pretty sure that the full list of 2.2 features wasn't released until the day that 2.2 was released (not counting unofficial leaks). On that basis, don't think Google will release a full feature list for 2.3 until release day.

Comment: Thanks for the information, i was unaware of that. I will keep a look out for the release notes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [2.3 Gingerbread user's guide](http://static.googleusercontent.com/external_content/untrusted_dlcp/www.google.com/en/us/googlephone/AndroidUsersGuide-2.3.pdf) has been released,  Chapter 2: Connecting to Networks and Devices doesn't mention ad-hoc wireless networks at all.